# Why Google Analytics uses New Image instead of JSONP

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, jsonp

if you need to send crosssite request you can do it via JSONP and via new Image(), if you use JSONP you can recive answer from server, if new Image - not, why GA uses new Image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Google Analytics does not need to send anything back to your browser after getting your information from the initial request.

They make you ping their server with a new request (creating a new Image guarantees that your browser won't cache the link) sending them all the information from your browser: UserAgent string, etc.

They don't need JSONP because they're not communicating so much as collecting data.

Comment: "creating a new Image guarantees that your browser won't cache the link" thanks man, I didn't know this , one more: if you use JSONP without js framework you will need to user crossbrowser XMLTHHPRequest (see wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)), new Image is much shorter

Comment: @andrew, you don't need XHR and js libs to make JSONP, just something like `<script src="urlToJSON?cb=mycallback"></script>`

Comment: @mic yep, but if I want to add this I need write much more than just new Image

Answer (score 0):

may be because they do not need any reply from the server. that is why they use `new Image()`.